# Matrix multiplication commutative with Simultaneous Diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that matrix multiplication in general is not commutative. So, in general:
$$A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}: A\cdot B \neq B \cdot A.$$
But for some matrices, this equation holds, such as Simultaneous diagonalization matrices ([reference to this](https://martin-thoma.com/when-is-matrix-multiplication-commutative/)). However, I have some questions about this case:

1. We must have: $A=T^{-1}D_AT$ and $B=T^{-1}D_BT$ with the same $T$?, which group of matrices can satisfy these criteria?
2. If $A$ and $B$ are Simultaneous Diagonalizable matrices, Can $A+B$ be Simultaneous Diagonalizable?

Comment: *Same T* corresponds to the definition of *Simultaneous diagonalization matrices*. This means that these matrices are diagonalisable *and* have the same eigenvectors. Concerning question 2., note that if $A$ and $B$ have same eigenvectors, then $A+B$ have same eigenvectors too.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how can we independently generate a number of Simultaneous Diagonalizable matrices?

Comment: You may try to generate the eigenvectors ($T$) , and the eigenvalues ($D_A$ and $D_B$).

Comment: Thank you very much. I have got this.